# Reuse code in certain methods of controllers

Tags: laravel

I have some code I use in some methods inside different controllers.
What is the best way to implement it as a function outside the controllers?
I think the `abort(404);` might be an issue here...

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request, $id = false)
    {
        if (empty($id))
        {
            $id = Auth::user()->id;
        }

        if (Auth::user()->isSuperUser())
        {
            $user = User::where('id', $id)
                ->withTrashed()->first();

            if (!$user)
            {
                 abort(404);
            }
        }
        elseif (Auth::user()->id == $id)
        {
            $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        }
        else
        {
            abort(401);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you use `User` model for authentication ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a trait and include it when you want to use it.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Validation\UnauthorizedException;

trait UserFinder
{
  public function find(Request $request, $id = false)
  {
    if (empty($id)) {
      $id = auth()->id();
    }

    if (auth()->user()->isSuperUser()) {
      $user = User::where('id', $id)
        ->withTrashed()->first();

      if (!$user) {
        throw new ModelNotFoundException();
      }
    } elseif (auth()->id() == $id) {
      $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    } else {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }

    return $user;
  }
}
```

And in your controller you can use it like this

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Validation\UnauthorizedException;

class UserController extends Controller
{
  use UserFinder;
  
  public function index(Request $request, $id = false)
  {
    try {
      $user = $this->find($request, $id);

      // rest of your code here.
    } catch (UnauthorizedException $ex) {
      abort(401);
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
      abort(404);
    }
  }
}
```